# Slicing list of json objects into sublists

Tags: python, list, slice

I have the following json

```
[
  {
    "e": {
      "i": 1,
      "t": 1
    },
    "c": [
      {
        "i": 3,
        "s": 0
      }
    ],
    "a": [
      {
        "i": 3,
        "s": 1,
        "w": 0,
        "d": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "e": {
      "i": 1,
      "t": 1
    },
    "c": [
      {
        "i": 3,
        "s": 0
      }
    ],
    "a": [
      {
        "i": 3,
        "s": 1,
        "w": 0,
        "d": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

it could hold n elements where each element has different size. In this example it holds two elements with equal size.

I want to be able to slice the list up in n sublist of m size. The size m is specified in how many chars of json each sublist hold, without splitting the objects.

I've tried search here on stackoverflow and i found the following code which seems be working for a lot of people

Assume that the json list i posted in the start of the thread is called "dataList"

```
  lists = [dataList[i:i+82] for i in range(0, len(dataList), 82)]
```

What i understand of it is that i am specifying that i want each sublist to be of size 82. I was expecting two sublists in my lists variable, but i am just getting the exact same.

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: So the big problem you face is a multi level dictionary and if I had to guess you are seeing lists containing dictionaries in your `lists` variable.  Do the numbers represent anything?

Comment: Yes, the key values are just shortned. It's data which i need to send to an Arduino, and i can't handle over 1kb data in memory, so i need to have multiple chunks instead of having e.g. a 12kb json file.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I see so from what I gather you are trying to use dataList as a `String`  try looking at the json as what it is an object.

Comment: `len(dataList)` is only 2 -- because it contains two dictionaries. As @user2097159 said, it sounds like you're trying to treat is a string.